# How to raise event when UITextField inside the UIView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have tried to raise event for `UITextfield` when inside the `UIView`.

```
UIView view = new UIView();
UITextField textfield = new UITextField();
textField.TouchDown += textfield_TouchDown;
view.AddSubView(textfield);

// event not raised.
void textfield_TouchDown(object s, EventArgs args)
{
    // your code here
}
```

I have tried to add the gesture, but it is not working.

**Please refer the below code**

```
UITextField textfield = new UITextField();
UITapGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
gestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
if (textfield != null)
{
    textfield.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    gestureRecognizer.AddTarget(() =>
    {
         // click event for lable/image
         OnTapped(gestureRecognizer);
    });
    textfield.AddGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer);
}

private void OnTapped(UITapGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Please suggest your idea on this this?

Regards,

Srinivasan

Comment: Are you setting the bounds/frame of that UIView and adding it your view controller? (I do not see that code)

Comment: just setting frame for rect calculation